# How to change Java ROME parser default socket timeout?

Tags: java, sockets, timeout, rome

I am parsing a fair amount of RSS feeds in cascade using Java ROME as my XML parser. 
Sometimes one of the RSS feeds might be unreachable because of network issues, which results in a Socket timeout when trying to create the XMLReader object ( new XMLReader(url)).

The problem is that the default timeout lasts about 2 decades and when it happens it's slowing down the whole process.

Is there a way to change the default socket timeout in Java ROME?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create `XMLReader object ( new XMLReader(url))`, you already have a `URLConnection` object which is passed as the argument for `XMLReader`. Call, `setConnectTimeout(long)` of URLConnection and set your timeout value. I dont think Rome provides any connection timeout options

Comment: Thank you. The object passed as argument to the XMLReader constructor is actually a java.net.URL object, which doesn't provide any setConnectTimeout method. Actually, I could wrap the java.net.URL object into a URLConnection object and pass that to the XMLReader constructor, but then I'm asked to implement a connect() method for the URLConnection object and I have no idea of hat to put in it..

Comment: `XmlReader` can be constructed with both URL and URLConnection. check http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/rome/rome/0.9/rome-0.9-javadoc.jar!/com/sun/syndication/io/XmlReader.html

Comment: Thank you very much. Solved.  
             `URLConnection urlConnection = new URL(rssSource).openConnection();`       `urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(4000);`  
`reader = new XmlReader(urlConnection);`  
`feed = new SyndFeedInput().build(reader);`

Comment: You may also want to give attention to `URLConnection.setReadTimeout(int timeoutMs)`